# Hibernate Search Hang when doing indexing

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem where the hibernate search mass indexing stuck/hang in production environment while it's working fine in development environment.
Following is the code for the mass indexing:

```
fullTextSession.purgeAll(entityClass);

fullTextSession
        .createIndexer( entityClass )
        .batchSizeToLoadObjects(Integer.parseInt(getConfigProperty(CommonConstants.CONFIGKEY_INDEXER_BATCH_SIZE))) //200
        .cacheMode( CacheMode.IGNORE )
        .threadsToLoadObjects(Integer.parseInt(getConfigProperty(CommonConstants.CONFIGKEY_INDEXER_THREAD_COUNT))) //5
        .idFetchSize(Integer.parseInt(getConfigProperty(CommonConstants.CONFIGKEY_INDEXER_FETCH_SIZE))) //1000
        .progressMonitor( new SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor() ) //a MassIndexerProgressMonitor implementation
        .startAndWait();
```

The following is the log that show where it hangs/stuck:

```
[Server:server-one] 2016-10-25 19:28:53860 INFO  (SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor.java:71) HSEARCH000027: Going to reindex 9 entities
```

Is there anyway I can findout what is the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the data volume in your production environment is significantly greater than that in your development environment?

Comment: The application seems to hang when trying to index the records for the first table. The table has 9 records only.
 
There’s a difference however, for the setup in Dev environment and Prod environment. In Prod environment, the web application is connecting to a PGPOOL instead of PostgreSQL instance. I’ve tried to perform the indexing by connecting to the PostgreSQL instance directly instead of through PGPOOL and it works fine. Any idea what maybe the cause?